# Нужны ли запятые перед "что" и вокруг "собственно"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая во фразах:

- Нам было(,) что показать.
- И он(,) собственно(,) прав.

Comment: Вообще такие вопросы лучше задавать здесь: http://rus.stackexchange.com/ А этот форум, я так понимаю, создан для иностранцев изучающих русский язык.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Нам было что показать.

Rosenthal, 114.1:

> Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний, например: *сделать как следует* (как полагается, как подобает), *выполнить как должно* (как надо, как нужно), *хватать что подвернется, явиться как ни в чем не бывало, говорить что в ум взбредёт, добиваться во что бы то ни стало, приходить когда вздумается, спрятаться кто куда успел, не лезть куда не следует, ночевать где придется, делай что хочешь, бери что нравится, спасайся кто может, есть что дают, будь что будет, идти куда глаза глядят, живите как знаете, приглашу к себе кого пожелаю, заплатил Бог знает сколько, кричит что есть мочи, рассказать все как есть, выдумывали кто во что горазд, достать что нужно* (но: *достать все, что нужно*), *черт знает что у них творится, городить черт знает что, поживиться чем можно, дать чего не жалко, картина чудо как хороша, страсть как интересно, ужас как трудно, беда как плохо.*

---

> И он, собственно, прав.

Rosenthal, 99.5:

> Запятыми выделяются вводные слова и словосочетания. Различается несколько основных групп вводных слов по их значению: … вводные слова, выражающие отношение к стилю речи, к характеру и способу изложения: *словом, одним словом, иными словами, другими словами, иначе говоря, коротко говоря, попросту сказать, мягко выражаясь, если можно так сказать, если можно так выразиться, с позволения сказать, лучше сказать, так сказать, что называется* и др.: слова *собственно, вообще, вернее, точнее, скорее* и т.п. являются вводными, если после них можно добавить слово *говоря*. Например: *… Правление уполномочило его ускорить работы, то есть, иными словами, он сам себя уполномочил к этому (Куприн); А Клавдия ушла, вернее, убежала, смущенно укрыв шалью лицо (Ю. Лаптев);*

Answer (score 5):

> Нам было что показать.

Нет, запятая не нужна, "*было что показать*" - составное сказуемое.

> И он, собственно, прав.

Нужны запятые, потому что здесь "*собственно*" - вводное слово.